# How to get one list item which is different on a specific property from the rest in C#, without looping through the list?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application with a list of `Button`s. At any given time, only one of them is `Visible`. I want to be able to programmatically get that `Button`.

I  DID try to go through the list using a `foreach` loop, and than check whether the current `Button` is visible:

```
var buttons = ButtonsHolder.Children.OfType<Button>().ToList();

foreach(var button in buttons)
{
    if(button.IsVisible)
        return button;
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this, without having to loop through the list?

Comment: Is there only ever 1 button active? when you make it active - you could just keep a record of it

Comment: It's an idea, but I am more interested in the general idea of finding an element by a property. Thanks ALOT!

Comment: `return ButtonsHolder.Children.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(b=>b.IsVisible);` is the same but shorter

Comment: @ASh - Well, it works, so why don't you put it in an answer so I could accept it? :)

Comment: @ASh it's more elegant, but still iterates thought the list.

Comment: @DovydasSopa, to be more precise it iterates a sequence (`IEnumerable<Button>`) without making a temporary buttons list. but yes, it is still a loop inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible to rewrite the code sample using `FirstOrDefault` method with a predicate

```
return ButtonsHolder.Children
                    .OfType<Button>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(b => b.IsVisible);
```

Comment: Elegant enough for me :)

Comment: Worth noting that this is just "code sugar" for exactly what you've already implemented.